# "Не вернувшимся казакам, защищавшим Родину"? или "Невернувшимся казакам, защищавшим Родину"

Tags: орфография, слитно-раздельно

Как правильно писать: "Не вернувшимся казакам, защищавшим Родину"? или "Невернувшимся казакам, защищавшим Родину"? ответить, ссылаясь на правила русского языка.

Comment: Вероятно, нужен контекст.

Comment: Ссылаясь на правила русского языка... Вероятно, ДЗ.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что это домашнее задание.

Answer (score 4):

Правильно: **Невернувшимся казакам, защищавшим Родину** (слитное написание причастия при отсутствии зависимых слов).

**Пример названия:** памятник воинам, не вернувшимся с Великой Отечественной войны, в Ростове-на-Дону.

Памятник называется **«Невернувшимся»,** а в народе его называют"Журавли" – в связи с известным стихотворением народного поэта Дагестана Расула Гамзатова «Журавли», ставшего не менее известной песней-реквиемом по всем погибшим на войне.

[Мемориальный комплекс Невернувшимся с войны | eSosedi](http://ru.esosedi.org/RU/ROS/1000480151/memorialnyiy_kompleks_nevernuvshimsya_s_voynyi/)